# Why are the inner divs height depending on the container width?

Tags: html, css, height, margin, percentage

I have looked at this to long and I have no clue what is happening here. Can anybody give me a hint why this works like this? Firefox, Chrome, IE all have the same result.

In this example the **width** of the container is set to **1000px** and the inner divs are overflowing the container:
http://jsfiddle.net/S65Hv/

In this example I have only changed the **width** of the container to **300px**, the result is that the height of the inner items are within the container, no overflow:
http://jsfiddle.net/5EwTG/

Code:

```
<style>
    .container {
        position: absolute; 
        top: 10px; 
        left: 10px; 
        width: 1000px; 
        height: 300px; 
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    .item {
        width: 48%;
        height: 48%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 1%;
    }

    .innerItem {
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }        
</style>    

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="innerItem">
        </div>        
    </div>        
    <div class="item">
        <div class="innerItem">
        </div>           
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="innerItem">
        </div>           
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="innerItem">
        </div>           
    </div>    
</div>
```

The height of inner divs are in percentage and have the total sum of 100% including the margin.

In my knowledge 100% of 300px height is always the same and should be independent of the width.

Is this behavior by design? And if so, why?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? I can't see any unlogical behavior there.

Comment: I expect that the height of the item divs are always within the container. Height of container = 300px, height of item = 48% + 2% margin = 50% * 2 = 100%, 100% of 300px = 300px. No more and no less.

Comment: But when I set the **width** of the container to 1000px (instead of 300px), the height is always 300px, the item divs are overflowing the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how percentage margins are supposed to work.  Percentage margins are based off of a percentage of the width.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am still puzzled. Isn't this strange? How can I have the items distributed on the height of the container?

Comment: It is a bit strange/unintuitive, but unfortunately is how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Back to the drawing board :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `margin: 1%` it is setting all 4 margins based on the *width* of the parent element. So, the width is affecting your height in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer in the same layout context as their parents. They have no idea where or how large their parent items are.

Therefore you cannot use percentage units and expect them to be sized in relation to the parent item.

Comment: What about `position: relative;`? That's exactly what he is using and it does what you say is not possible.

Comment: Where is my answer do I say something is not possible?

Comment: "Therefore you cannot use percentage units and expect them to be sized in relation to the parent item." ???

Comment: No, I'm saying they don't behave the way you EXPECT them to.

Comment: 1. I just quoted your own statement, which is apparently wrong. 2. How is my way of expecting how they behave in relation to our argument? I expect them to behave like they actually do, but that is not the subject here.

Answer (score 0):

The margin of 1% appears to be set based on the width. You could calculate the margin using js and then set it.

Answer (score 0):

Your margin is affecting the overflow of the inner boxes.  There are many approaches to this, but you can adjust the margin and fix the height and width of the inner `div` containers.  Here would be a fixed example:

http://jsfiddle.net/S65Hv/21/

As @Aaron said, you can use JS to help with this.

Comment: Thanx, but I want to have a full percentage layout and not with pixels and preferable html and css only. I think I have a solution...
http://jsfiddle.net/ras8R/4/